# Android - Presenting Facebook Messenger app causes crash

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to share a link with the new Facebook Messenger dialog on Android. I use the new Facebook SDK 3.14.1.

When I load the Fragment which is going to present the Facebook Dialog i do this, taken straight from the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share#message-dialog

In `onActivityCreated` for my Fragment

```
    // Check if the Facebook app is installed and we can present the share dialog
    FacebookDialog.MessageDialogBuilder builder = new FacebookDialog.MessageDialogBuilder(getActivity())
        .setLink("https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share/")
        .setName("Message Dialog Tutorial")
        .setCaption("Build great social apps that engage your friends.")
        .setPicture("http://i.imgur.com/g3Qc1HN.png")
        .setDescription("Allow your users to message links from your app using the Android SDK.")
        .setFragment(this);

    // If the Facebook app is installed and we can present the share dialog
    if (builder.canPresent()) {
      // Enable button or other UI to initiate launch of the Message Dialog
        Log.i("","FACEBOOK MESSENGER IS INSTALLED");
        FacebookDialog dialog = builder.build();
        dialog.present();
    }  else {
      // Disable button or other UI for Message Dialog 
        Log.i("","FACEBOOK MESSENGER IS NOT INSTALLED");
    }
```

The check works fine and I get the log message "FACEBOOK MESSENGER IS INSTALLED" (which it is). But when i try to present the dialog I get the erroe:

[image: Error]

Does anyone know what this could be? I have tried on multiple devices. Has anyone ever succesfully done this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an application id, and did you set it in your manifest?

Comment: @MingLi Dude that was it! Didn't think I needed to do that since you don't need to be logged in to use the Messenger Dialog. Thank you!